# publishing test project with referenced main project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, csproj

I want to publish my WebApi, including my test projects!

my project structure

```
\
 MyProject.Models
 MyProject.Service
 MyProject.Web
 MyProject.Test
```

`MyProject.Test` references `MyProject.Web` because the Startup classes is needed for `IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>`.

When I publish my executable main project `MyProject.Web` - it did not publish the test project. That's right, but how do I achieve that, the test project is published with the .Web Project?

I want to publish the test project without the references of .Web & .Service & .Models.

thats my MyProject.Test.pubxml

```
...
<ItemGroup>
   <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>MyProject.Models.*;MyProject.Service.*;MyProject.Web.*</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
</ItemGroup>
```

but this is not working!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's not a real solution but I deleted the `.Test` project and merged it, into a subfolder from the `.Web` project.